# (bat) Доступ к переменной из if

Tags: bat, переменные

Понадобилось сгородить bat файл и столкнулся с проблемой.
Код с циклом, внутри которого есть условие. И переменная которая назначается если условие срабатывает. Ожидаю увидеть в echo qwe потом ewq, но вижу изначально только присвоенное значение вне цикла (2 раза).

```
 @echo off 
    SetLocal EnableExtensions
    Set a=q
    Set C=1 3 2
    FOR %%x IN (%C%) DO (
    IF %%x==1 ( 
    Set a=qwe
    echo %a%
    )
    IF %%x==2 (
    Set a=ewq
echo %a%
    )
    )
    pause
```

если убираю изначальное присваивание Set a=q то получаю и вовсе "режим вывода команд echo отключен" и все. Как назначить и обратиться к переменной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ожидаю увидеть в echo qwe потом ewq, но вижу изначально только присвоенное значение вне цикла (2 раза).

Надо включить `EnableDelayedExpansion` и использовать `!a!`.

При выключенном (не установленном) EnableDelayedExpansion значение переменных фиксируется на момент начала блока, и любое изменение их игнорируется. Даже если оно было абы изменено предыдущей строкой.

При включенном EnableDelayedExpansion значение переменной аналогично фиксируется, и получается зафиксированное значение при обращении, если используется знак процента, либо изменённое, если используется восклицательный знак.

Код для разбора:

```
@echo off 
cls
SetLocal 
set test=test
echo Without EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (1) do (
    set test=altered
    echo %test%
    echo !test!
)
echo finally: %test%
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set test=test
echo.
echo With EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%x in (3) do (
    set test=altered
    echo %test%
    echo !test!
)
echo finally: %test%
```

> если убираю изначальное присваивание `Set a=q` то получаю и вовсе "режим вывода команд echo отключен"

Надо предусматривать такое событие.

Вот правильный код:

```
@echo off 
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set a=q
Set C=1 3 2
FOR %%x IN (%C%) DO (
    IF "%%x"=="1" ( 
        Set a=qwe
        echo !a!
    )
    IF "%%x"=="2" (
        Set a=ewq
        echo !a!
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: спасибо. в чем именно суть вызова вида !переменная! ?

Comment: @user8494502 Добавил объяснение.